# Como mudar a imagem de uma ImageView de forma dinâmica

Tags: android

Olá, preciso de ajuda para mudar uma imagem de forma dinâmica

Segue meu código:

```
st = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
int RID = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(Bundle_img, "drawable", getPackageName());
st.setImageResource(RID );
```

o código acima não está substituindo a imagem anterior.

Comment: Como está vindo a String `Bundle_img` ?

Comment: Bundle_img = "red"

Comment: Amigo Obrigado, já encontrei o problema. Cometi um FO falha operacional. :D Minha imagem está com ic_situacao_+(Bundle_img) OBrigado

Comment: Coloca a solução aqui pra ajudar os outros no futuro. obg

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nome_imagem)`.

Exemplo:

```
Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nome_imagem);
img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```